Is missing data necessarily seen as fraud?
I normally work on system identification, focusing on continuous-time fractional-order models. In many occasions I perform Monte Carlo runs to test my algorithms' performances. I became aware after a journal publication that one of my data files got accidentally erased, which means if someone wanted to see my data I would be able to provide them almost all the collected data (let's say around 85-90%), but not the totality of it because of the erased file.
How would you consider this situation on the ethical side? (Just to be clear: the file was lost after the publication was completed.)

If you regenerated the results, how different would your conclusion be?

the code able to reproduce a Monte Carlo simulation is not lost and, even though the results would not be bit by bit identical, the conclusions and tendency would remain intact

Seems a pretty big leap from missing data to concerns about potential fraud accusations. Is there more to consider here?

Thankfully not, I just tend to be really critical and dubious about my work.

If your code is still available and re-running it produces the same result within statistical error, I would not even consider that something is lost. After all, data files can be rather big and in certain situations they are even impossible to store. Moreover, for the majority of published papers some data are lost after a few years. so in the situation you described I would not worry about it at all.

@Vosoni: please avoid writing answers in the comments.

For a monte-carlo run in particular, saving the seed for your randomness might be sufficient. There's cases where it won't be (if you have multiple threads sharing a PRNG), but if it's controllable, that's a nice way to be able to regenerate the data on demand.

This is not a problem.

Monte Carlo runs should be "mostly" reproducible regardless of the exact seed chosen. So your qualitative results should still be reproducible, even if you can no longer do a bit-for-bit reproduction of the paper.
If someone tried to reproduce your results and failed, it would be nice if you had the actual data so that you could debug it. But this is (unfortunately) far from a requirement; many authors never respond to such queries. Worst case, someone could publish an article disputing your paper. I do not know how likely this is to happen in your field, but I suspect it is unlikely unless your paper is really groundbreaking and gets a lot of attention.
In any case, there is not really an ethical issue here. You did not intentionally falsify the data. While keeping stuff like this is a best practice, it is not an absolute requirement in the way that getting IRB approval is. And certainly you can't be expected to hold onto old datasets in perpetuity.


While I agree in general, note that certain sorts/levels of carelessness can be an ethical problem.

Well, if you're so careless that you're routinely publishing irreproducible crap and getting your papers retracted, that's just "being terrible at your job." Which I guess is a type of ethical issue.

the fact one file was accidentally lost does not equate to the method being irreproducible, as the programs and functions still exist and would produce similar results once more

Isn’t that exactly what I said?

Fraud would imply an intent to deceive.
If you can regenerate sufficiently similar results with a new simulation, it would be hard for anyone to argue what sort of benefit you would have derived from such deception.
You can avoid this problem in the future by uploading your data to some sort of archiving service at the time of submission. However, I wouldn't let yourself get too anxious over it this time.
